# Replacing a RAID1 disk with a different model

Tags: hard-drive, raid-1

When I replace a disk in a 2-disk RAID1 array, how do I know if a proposed replacement disk is actually suitable?

Just to make the question more concrete, the disk to be replaced is a 1TB Seagate ST31000524AS.  There are millions of kinds of 1TB disks one can buy.  How can I determine what is really suitable as a replacement for this disk?

The only answers people have been able to supply so far are: (a) get the exact same model; or (b) any disk of the same size is fine.  Does anyone have a more refined answer?

Comment: They're pretty much all suitable just so long as it's the same or greater capacity, speed and cache. If the disk is too small then it won't be used in the array. If the disk is slower then the array will work to the slowest device and if the caches are smaller then you may notice some bottleneck (performance) problems. They're not really "problems", rather performance degraders. A RAID-1 is a mirror so, I'd say, if the disk fits and has the same properties as the existing, then it should be perfectly suitable. The bonus for RAID is that it often doesn't matter about the disks you use.

Comment: Many, however, do recommend using slightly higher performance disks for such environments as NAS devices because they are often required to be "constantly on" so disk manufacturers offer some special disks that they have made for these circumstances...

Answer (score 0):

I have recently experienced a similar situation and mixing drive brands was fine.

I have a small Lenovo ix2-dl that housed two 3TB Seagate drives in RAID 1. These were identical in size, speed and cashe. Then one of the drives failed after 2.5 years.

I replaced the failed Seagate with a WD Red 3 TB variable speed drive, same cashe drive. The RAID rebuilt and I have had no issue. I stuck with the idea of same or larger size.

Because it is for home use, I have not tracked it's performance as the tasks are done during the night when everyone is sleeping. This is getting the job done.

This was my experiment with mixing drives and was prepared to get a second identical WD Red, but it is not needed (Unless I want a back up on hand in the event the other older Seagate fails).

I went with the notion of same size or bigger and cashe matching.